# How to import dicom images to OsiriX/Horos

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective-C and I'm not sure what's the best way to finish my current project. Basicaly, my project is a plugin for a medical software called OsiriX. And my question is, how can I import DICOM images to OsiriX programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the DICOM files to `Documents/OsiriX Data/INCOMING.noindex`.
OsiriX scans this folder periodically, looking for new DICOM files.